# Add TabBarItem including action to existing UITabBarController's more menu

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to have an logout item in the more section of the UITabBarController I created using the storyboard. How can I add it without removing all the other connections and how can I listen to its click?

Answer (score 0):

A UITabBarController manages an array of view controllers. If the number of view controllers in that array exceeds six, then the first four items in the array are displayed in the tab bar and the  button appears in index 4 (the fifth spot) by default. The More view is actually a navigation controller that displays all the views in the array and allows the user to select which view they wish to see or edit which views will reside within tab bar.

If you want to add a custom element to the More view without a corresponding UIViewController in storyboard, then you need to subclass your UITabBarController to display that item because the  view does not reside in the array of view controllers and is therefore not editable.

The simplest way to display a logout item in the More view is to create a corresponding logout UIViewController and set the UITabBarController as the root controller.

For more info on UITabBarController, see the Apple documentation: [moreNavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me more information on how I can listen to the click of the logout item without opening a new view for the 'LogoutViewController'?